# Displaying gSSURGO data from a geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase

Can someone walk me through the steps necessary to display data from one of the "outer" tables in the geodatabases available through gSSURGO?  For instance, what joins do I need to perform to get saturated hydraulic conductivity (*ksat_r* in the *chorizons* table) to show within ArcMap.